# How to determine the transparency color of a bitmap

Tags: .net, imaging

I know you can programmatically [determine the tranparency color of a .gif](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/339722/how-to-get-gif-transparency-color-in-vc-6-0-and-vc-2005)

Is there a way to do the same for a Bitmap?

Right now, I am doing this heuristically by sampling around the outer edge but of course this is not 100% reliable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't believe the BMP file format supports the concept of transparency. My understanding is that if BMP images are used with transparency, it's using an application-defined colour, like RGB(255,0,255) to specify transparent areas.

Comment: Correct. Sometimes applications will use the first pixel of a bitmap to designate the transparent color such as Magenta. But this is entirely up to the application as to how it wants to mask the bitmap.

Comment: +1 Yeah, that's the conclusion I came to. Just hoping that there is a hole in my reasoning. Will leave it open for a while.

Comment: I believe there is some support for a bmpx format that saves the Alpha  channel but @Jason and @Josh are absolutely correct for straight bitmap.

Answer (score -1):

What you may do is:

- To sample the occluded image.
- Apply canny edge detection algorithm to detect outer edges of the object in your bitmap image.
- You can be approximate, you may also need to tweak a bit to get only the outer edges.
- Then you can perform an intersection of these 2 samples to get the occluded image, across the bitmap image edges.
- By now, you will be having 2 images. Make sure the occlusion-extracted image is transparent and on top.
- Just put the original bitmap beneath the extracted image and you'll achieve transparency with your bitmap image too! :)